# Problem with get all the link from String Regular Expression

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

Below is the regex I tried to get all the urls from string:

```
(?:(?:(?:[a-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)?[a-z0-9.-]+|(?:www\.|[-;:&=+$‌​,\w]+@)[a-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[+~%\/.\w-]*)?\??(?:[-+=&;%@.\w]*)#?\w*)?)
```

It is working fine here, check this out http://regexr.com/3cgrq

but if I use pattern matching in salesforce get multiple error.

> Illegal character sequence '/' in string literal.

If I remove all the `\` then I get another error

> System.StringException: Invalid regex: Dangling meta character '?'

Pls try to execute below code in developer console

```
String myvar = 'raewaferwww.dilyan.co.ukhrewadfea'+
''+
'<span style="color: #5f604b;">'+
'<span style="font: signacondcolumn-book;">'+
'<span style="font-size: 8.0pt;">https://www.merchant.com/store</span>'+
'</span>'+
'</span>'+
'<br>'+
'<a href\'="www.account.com">Account</a>';

// First, instantiate a new Pattern object "MyPattern"
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('(?:(?:(?:[a-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)?[a-z0-9.-]+|(?:www\.|[-;:&=+$‌​,\w]+@)[a-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[+~%\/.\w-]*)?\??(?:[-+=&;%@.\w]*)#?\w*)?)');

// Then instantiate a new Matcher object "MyMatcher"
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(myvar);

while (MyMatcher.find()) { 
    System.debug(MyMatcher.group());
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in Salesforce?

Comment: @MarkPond couple of error I am getting like `Illegal character sequence '\/' in string literal.` If I remove all the `\\` then I get another error like reg exp not valid

Comment: did you try \\/ as I believe you have to escape the escape...

Comment: no @Eric let me try that

Comment: Can I ask why this question got downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after no of changes. I finally able to get the correct expression

```
(?:(?:(?:[a-z]{3,9}:(?://)?)(?:[-;:&=+$,w]+@)?[a-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=+$??,w]+@)[a-z0-9.-]+)((?:/[+~%/.w-]*)?\\??(?:[-+=&;%@.w]*)#?w*)?)
```

This will return all the links from String

[image]

---

Code

```
String myvar = 'raewaferwww.dilyan.co.ukhrewadfea'+
''+
'<span style="color: #5f604b;">'+
'<span style="font: signacondcolumn-book;">'+
'<span style="font-size: 8.0pt;">https://www.merchant.com/store</span>'+
'</span>'+
'</span>'+
'<br>'+
'<a href\'="www.account.com">Account</a>';


String myvar1 = '(?:(?:(?:[a-z]{3,9}:(?://)?)(?:[-;:&=+$,w]+@)?[a-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=+$??,w]+@)[a-z0-9.-]+)((?:/[+~%/.w-]*)?\\??(?:[-+=&;%@.w]*)#?w*)?)';

// First, instantiate a new Pattern object "MyPattern"
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(myvar1);

// Then instantiate a new Matcher object "MyMatcher"
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(myvar);

while (MyMatcher.find()) { 
    System.debug(MyMatcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your backslashes. So anywhere you have `\` needs to become `\\`.

```
(?:(?:(?:[a-z]{3,9}:(?:\\\\/\\\\/)?)(?:[-;:&=+$,\\\\w]+@)?[a-z0-9.-]+|(?:www\\\\.|[-;:&=+$\u200c\u200b,\\\\w]+@)[a-z0-9.-]+)((?:\\\\/[+~%\\\\/.\\\\w-]*)?\\\\??(?:[-+=&;%@.\\\\w]*)#?\\\\w*)?)
```

Comment: If I use this regex. Then my result don't return any URL's

Comment: Maybe you should try a simpler pattern. Your question is really about how to resolve the `illegal character` error, not how to make a regex that suits your needs. That would probably be more appropriate on Stack Overflow anyway.

Comment: what is the use if I modify expression. If that won't work as http://regexr.com/3cgrq then what is the use